# Unable to access openmdao-generated sqlite database keys

Tags: sqlite, openmdao

I am using OpenMDAO and the normal omdao recorder for a problem in both Unix and Linux, i.e. in my OpenMDAO-based python script I do:

```
    from openmdao.api import SqliteRecorder
    recname = 'DLCS_5MW.sqlite'
    recorder = SqliteRecorder(recname)
    top.driver.add_recorder(recorder)
```

After running the problem in my Unix setup, I am able to access the database as expected:

```
    >>> import sqlitedict
    >>> db = sqlitedict.SqliteDict('DLCS_5MW.sqlite','openmdao')
    >>> db.keys()
    ['metadata', 'rank0:Driver/1']
```

But when I run the problem in my Linux setup and load the database the same way, I instead get this:

```
    >>> db.keys()
    []
```

i.e. a keyless dictionary. I can see that the sqlite file itself does have information (like 1 GB worth); I just can seem to access it. I can verify that the problem is with the file itself and not with which operating system I am inspecting it on (i.e. I can successfully inspect a Unix-generated file on my Linux setup, but not the Linux-generated file on my Unix setup). This leads me to believe that there is some disjointedness going on between OpenMDAO and sqlite.

Initially I had supposed that the issue had to do with the Python installation (which includes sqlite, yes?) and OpenMDAO installation on my Linux machine, but I re-installed both to no avail (using Anaconda python). I have tried to find occurrences of similar issues outside of OpenMDAO--in just an sqlite context--but I am unfortunately not very well versed in sqlite and haven't been able to track down anything helpful. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: just to clarify, if you run your model on linux and take the sqlite file it generated then move it over to unix you can read that file?

Comment: Also, what version of linux are you working on? What version of OpenMDAO are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. If I run the model on linux and take the sqlite file over to unix, I still cannot read the sqlite file. The problem is with the linux-generated sqlite file itself. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.5 and OpenMDAO 1.7.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear you are having problems.

We have been changing the way we do case recording so that might be why you are having problems but I don't know why you would have different results on Linux versus Unix.

We don't have an `openmdao` table any more. The tables are now `metadata`, `iterations`, and `derivs`.

To see if there are issues with case recording, I installed OpenMDAO 1.7.3 on an Ubuntu system and ran the example on http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/usr-guide/tutorials/recording.html.

To see if the iteration data is in the sqlite file, I did:

```
import sqlitedict
db = sqlitedict.SqliteDict('paraboloid','iterations')
print db.keys()
```

with a result of

```
['rank0:SLSQP|1', 'rank0:SLSQP|2', 'rank0:SLSQP|3', 'rank0:SLSQP|4', 'rank0:SLSQP|5', 'rank0:SLSQP|6']
```

Does that help?

Thanks

Comment: Ah yes, that is definitely it! I had been unwittingly using a different version of OpenMDAO on my Unix machine, 1.6.4, that clearly still had the openmdao table instead of metadata, iterations, and derivs. I obviously missed that change whenever it happened. I can now access the data using the approach you've described. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting us know and for using OpenMDAO

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem for version 1.7.1 as well, but upgrade to 1.7.3 resolved the issue.  Also, I found my project's recorder sqlite database in my working directory for the Python IDE ( Spyder, Fedora Linux/Gnome) and was able of accessing the tables via Sqliteman GUI.  It was using the SQL GUI that revealed the presence of the openmdao table and thus a clue that I was using an old version.